# Ext Js and Adobe Air

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications, air, extjs

Can anyone reccomend some good tutorials for ext js and adobe air? The ones I have seen seem to start with you knowing a lot or already having a lot of code in place.

What I am looking for is a simple step by step guide that takes you through the basics of Ext Js in use with adobe air, in fact i suppose just a good Ext Js tutorial for begginers would be handy I just cant find anything.

Im looking to build a desktop app and need to get on it quickly, but Js is my weakness and the app has some complexity (dont they always!!).

So Question - What are the best Ext Js tutorials for begginners (preferbly with some adobe air thrown in, but not essentiall, one step at a time ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the best tutorials are on the Ext JS site itself.

[Ext JS Intro Tutorial](http://extjs.com/learn/Tutorial:Introduction_to_Ext_2.0)

Ext JS is large JS library that includes a lot of functionality from standard DOM manipulation through the one of the most comprehensive set of JavaScript UI components.  Since it's such a large API to learn, I found looking through the samples and the associated source code a the best way to learn.

[Ext JS Samples](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/samples.html)

It's handy to have the Ext JS API docs easily accessible and Jack Slocum's Ext JS Docs AIR app is nice.

[Ext JS API Docs AIR App](http://jackslocum.com/blog/2008/02/14/air-docs/)

If your JS isn't too strong, you may want to consider a different JavaScript library/framework.  Ext JS is great and some would argue it's the highest quality JS library/framework out there at least from a UI components perspective, but it takes some time to master it since it is so large.  If your only going to use a couple of the UI components then you may be ok, but once you get into more complex UI that includes many components and layouts it gets fairly involved.

Answer (score 2):

one more best resource i can suggest is www.adobeairtutorials.com